# How to get the annotations using the kubernetes API for python?

Tags: python, kubernetes

I have a Docker image that contains an application in python, running in Kubernetes as a deployment, I want to pass to that application some data. I used env vars but I would like to use annotations but I'm not sure how to read them, I saw that `V1ObjectMeta` has a field called `annotations` but I'm a bit lost of how to call it.

For example:

If my pod has this:

```
template:
  metadata:
    annotations:
      foo: "var"
```

How to read `foo: var` using the python program that is running inside the pod using the Kubernetes library?

Comment: Welcome! Please provide relevant code you have written so far, preferably a minimal, reproducible, example of the behavior you are experiencing along with an explanation of what is going wrong or what improvements you would like to make. As it is, there isn't much anyone here can help you with, because the question is vague.

Answer (score 5):

All you need is to get the pod object from Kubernetes API. It has the same structure as in `YAML` format, so once you have the data, the rest is trivial. See below:

```py
from kubernetes import client, config

config.load_incluster_config()
c = client.CoreV1Api()

pod = c.read_namespaced_pod(name="my-pod-name", namespace="my-namespace")

print(pod.metadata.annotations["foo"])
```