# Print annotations of kubernetes deployment in Python

Tags: python, kubernetes

I'm writing a python program that prints some kind of data of an existing `kubernetes` cluster as a first step.

I need to print the `annotations` of a given `deployment`. I tried a read the documentation and unfortunately got some lost. Anyone can show me an example?

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70952155/how-to-read-a-kubernetes-deployment-with-python-kubernetes-client/70952387#70952387
Add `print(deployment.metadata.annotations)` to the answer's snippet.

Comment: Another related answer: [How to get the annotation values using the kubernetes API for python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69382987/2745495)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the example python script,
https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/AppsV1Api.md#read_namespaced_deployment

Once you get the api_response, you may have to do,

```
print(api_response.metadata.annotations)
```